# Program is not throwing ArgumentOutOfRange Exception

Tags: c#, try-catch, expectations

I have a simple program that takes a number from the user and returns the number located at that position/index in an array. However, if the given number is not withing the index range, it throws an exception.
Here is my code:

```
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };    
            Console.WriteLine("input int");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("before");
            try
            {
                double n = 5 / k;
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            int l=arr[k];
            Console.WriteLine(l);
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {

                throw new ArgumentException("you cant divid by 0!");

            }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException("please give a number between 0-5");

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new ArgumentException("something went worng, please try again");

        }
        finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("after");
                Console.WriteLine("process compited!");
            }
```

The problem however is, if the entered number is 7, which is not within the range, it shows ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception .
What should I do in case I want the Exception to be like "please give a number between 0-5"? (using try-catch method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.8) and [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.8). 
You have to catch IndexOutOfRangeException instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use exceptions to direct your application logic flow. Better check proactively if the index is not too big for your array. This index number is an input from outside so you are entitled to put any guards on it you see fit.

Other than that @Ciubotariu Florin is right.

Comment: can you please explain what you are meaning?

Comment: If what you need is to get error message "please give a number between 0-5" when index is out of bounds, then just write an if statement before `int l=arr[k];` like this:
`if(k < 0 || k > 5) throw new ArgumentException("please give a number between 0-5");` instead of using try-catch block. This way you will be more explicit about your intentions.

Comment: yes I know, I am just experimenting with that because this is a new subject to me.